# Obtener porción de una matriz (submatriz)

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Este codigo
`a = np.arange(1,26).reshape((5,5))`
me genera la siguiente matriz

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8  9 10]
[11 12 13 14 15]
[16 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 25]
```

lo que deseo obtener es otra matriz, con los siguientes numeros

```
[12 13 14 15]
[17 18 19 20]
[22 23 24 25]
```

Lo unico que he podido hacer es generar lo siguiente usando `print(a[2:5])` y me genera la siguiente matriz

```
[11 12 13 14 15]
[16 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 25]
```

Comment: Prueba `a[2:,1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces `a[2:5]` estás aplicando una técnica conocida como slicing (rebanado). Llevabas buen camino, lo único que te faltaba era especificar el rango de columnas a usar y no solo las filas.

Por lo tanto, en tu caso deberías usar:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 26).reshape((5, 5))
b = a[2:, 1:]
```

que es equivalente (explícito):

```
b = a[2:6:1, 1:5:1]
```

Obviamente podrías generarlo directamente de más formas, una muy obvia:

```
a = np.array((np.arange(12, 16),
              np.arange(17, 21),
              np.arange(22, 26)))
```

### Algunos conceptos sobre rebanado en NumPy

La sintaxis básica podemos definirla como:

```
array[ind_fila_ini:ind_fila_fin + 1:paso, ind_columna_ini:ind_columna_fin + 1:paso, ...]
```

Si alguno de los extremos del intervalo no se especifica, se toma desde el inicio o el final:

- `[indice_fila_ini: ]` -> desde indice_fila_ini hasta la última fila incluida.
- `[: indice_fila_fin]` -> desde la primera fila hasta indice_fila_fin
- `[:]`                 -> todas las filas

lo mismo para el caso de las columnas. Si el array tiene más de dos dimenciones la sintaxis es la misma. Se puede usar ellipsis para simplificar la sintaxis en los casos en los que varias dimenciones son tomadas al completo:

```
arr[:, :, 2:6]
```

es equivalente a:

```
arr[.., 2:6]
```

Existe además la posibilidaad de agregar un tercer parámetro, el paso (step):

```
[indice__inicial: indice_final: paso]
```

esto permite seleccionar valores espaciados entre si según el valor del paso:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a[0:10:2]
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Si no se especifica se asume que el paso es 1.

Tienes una explicación más extensa y detallada en la documentación oficial (en ingles):

- [Basic slicing and indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)

Una advertencia, debes asumir por principio que el slicing en NumPy retorna una vista del array original y no una copia. Para entender el concepto de vista yo suelo usar el ejemplo de una plantilla perforada (vista) que sobreponemos sobre la pagina de un libro (array) y que solo nos deja ver ciertas palabras. Si tachamos alguna de esas palabras con la plantilla puesta tachamos los datos originales, el libro. Así mismo si quemas el libro (array recolectado y eliminado de memoria) te quedas sin vista.

Esto es importante, puede ser muy útil o generar errores inesperados:

> ```
> >>> a
> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
>        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
>        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
>        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
>        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
>
> >>> b = a[2:, 1:]
> >>> b 
> array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
>        [17, 18, 19, 20],
>        [22, 23, 24, 25]])
>
> >>> b[0:] = 7
>
> >>> b 
> array([[7, 7, 7, 7],
>        [7, 7, 7, 7],
>        [7, 7, 7, 7]])
>
> >>> a # <<<<<<<< TAMBIÉN SE MODIFICA A
> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
>        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
>        [11,  7,  7,  7,  7],
>        [16,  7,  7,  7,  7],
>        [21,  7,  7,  7,  7]])
> ```

En casos en los que este comportamiento no sea el deseado, mejor usar una copia explícita:

```
b = a[2:, 1:].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando *slicing* se puede recortar una parte de una matriz de numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# a = np.arange(12, 27).reshape(3, 5)[:, :-1]
a = np.arange(11, 26).reshape(3, 5)[:, 1:]
print(a)
```

Resultado:

```
[[12 13 14 15]
 [17 18 19 20]
 [22 23 24 25]]
```