# Reemplazar en matriz de ceros con otros valores en determinadas celdas

Tags: excel, pandas, bucles, numpy, matriz

Necesito resolver un problema en el cual llevo horas, he creado una matriz base [imagen 1] esta primera matriz es de 6x6 (6 filas x 6 columnas).
*Código al final
[matriz_t_excel_archivo](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lA2AMOvk-lppBUhT)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, también he creado una matriz de ceros de 6x36 (6 filas x 36 columnas) [imagen 2].

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema está en que no encuentro la manera de reemplazar los ceros por los valores que me dicta la matriz de base de 6x6, y cuya ubicación de columnas (4,5,6,7,8,9) viene dada por el vector de conexiones (4,5,6,7,8,9) del elemento 15 de la hoja de Excel, es decir, el final de la iteración del bucle for [imagen 3]. 
Es decir, en esta imagen muestra como debería estar llenada, para este caso con la matriz de 6x36.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho la retroalimentación, soy relativamente nuevo con la librería numpy de Python, ya que desde MatLab si lo pude conseguir, pero necesito hacerlo desde Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

ex = pd.ExcelFile('matriz_t.xlsx')
hoja = ex.parse('Hoja1')

columnas = 36

for n in range(0,len(hoja)):
    A = hoja['ELEMENTO #'][n]
    B = hoja['1(i)'][n]
    C = hoja['2(i)'][n]
    D = hoja['3(i)'][n]
    E = hoja['1(j)'][n]
    F = hoja['2(j)'][n]
    G = hoja['3(j)'][n]
    H = hoja['X(i)'][n]
    I = hoja['Y(i)'][n]
    J = hoja['X(j)'][n]
    K = hoja['Y(j)'][n]

    L = math.sqrt((J-H)**2+(K-I)**2)
    lx = (J-H)/L
    ly = (K-I)/L

    ceros = np.zeros((6, columnas))

    matriz_base = np.array([[lx, ly, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [-ly, lx, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, lx, ly, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, -ly, lx, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que ceros y matriz_base son arrays de NumPy, puedes asignar directamente la matriz base a la submatriz correspondiente indizando sobre ella:

```
ceros[:, [A - 1, B - 1, C - 1, D - 1, E - 1, F - 1, G - 1]] = matriz_base
```

Ten en cuenta que Python y NumPy tiene **indizado basado en 0**, no en 1. Es decir, el primer elemento de un array tiene índice 0, no 1. Por eso resto uno a cada indice.

- [Obtener porción de una matriz (submatriz)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/336768/15089)

El código completo podría quedar:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


COLUMNAS = 36

ex = pd.ExcelFile('matriz_t.xlsx')
hoja = ex.parse('Hoja1')

hoja['L'] = np.sqrt(
    (hoja['X(j)'] - hoja['X(i)']) ** 2 + (hoja['Y(j)'] - hoja['Y(i)']) ** 2
    )
hoja["lx"] = (hoja['X(j)'] - hoja['X(i)']) / hoja['L']
hoja["ly"] = (hoja['Y(j)'] - hoja['Y(i)']) / hoja['L']

ceros = np.zeros((6, COLUMNAS))

cols = hoja.loc[:, ["1(i)", "2(i)", "3(i)", "1(j)", "2(j)", "3(j)","lx", "ly"]]
for _, i1, i2, i3, j1, j2, j3, lx, ly in cols.itertuples():
    matriz_base = np.array(
        [[ lx,  ly,   0,   0,   0,   0],
         [-ly,  lx,   0,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  lx,  ly,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0, -ly,  lx,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1]]
    )
    ceros[:, [i1 - 1, i2 - 1, i3 - 1, j1 - 1, j2 - 1 , j3 - 1]] = matriz_base
```

Que resulta en:

> ```
> [[ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
>  [-0.  1.  0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -0.  1.  0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -0.  1.  0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.]
>  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
>  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
>  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
>  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta me has dado un poco mas de luces para resolver el caso, aún así lo que busco es conseguir una diagonal de unos 3 a 8, contando desde cero, pero aparecen más -1's regados por toda la matriz, lo pude resolver con MatLab pero con Python aún no, he subido una actualización de mi pregunta en el foro para más detalles, muchas gracias por la retroalimentación.