# Dividir elementos entre una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero **dividir** los elementos de una lista haciendo que el **segundo** se divida entre el **primero** y el **tercero** entre el **segundo** y asi hasta el final de la lista.

```
Lista = [2, 4, 8, 32]
```

En este caso quisiera que las siguientes operaciones ***4/2, 8/4, 32/8*** se ejecuten todas a la vez o **automáticamente**.

Necesito que se haga todo **automaticamente** para poder replicarlo en una lista que sea mucho más larga

Si hay alguna forma de agilizar el proceso tambien podria utilizar la libreria Pandas o Numpy para agilizar el proceso y que la division entre 0 suelte un valor NaN

Comment: No es válido que le escribas cerrado al título de tu pregunta, si la respuesta dada te ayudó entonces lo correcto es marcarla como aceptada, *esa es la forma de agradecer en SO en español*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de usar Python estándar yo prefiero usar dos iteradores junto a `zip` (consumiendo un item de uno primero) para llevar a cabo el "rolling".

```
l = [2, 7, 8, 0, 32, 5]

nan = float("nan")
dividendo, divisor = iter(l), iter(l)
next(dividendo)
res = [a / b if b!=0 else nan for a, b in zip(dividendo, divisor)]
```

> ```
> >>> res
> [3.5, 1.1428571428571428, 0.0, nan, 0.15625]
> ```

En el caso de NumPy, basta con usar dos [rebanados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/336768/15089) y aplicar la operación vectorizada sobre ellos, solo debemos manejar el warning de la división entre 0 y cambiar los valores `inf` resultantes por NaN:

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.array((2, 7, 8, 0, 32, 5))

with np.errstate(divide="ignore"):
    res = arr[1:] / arr[:-1]

res[res == np.inf] = np.nan
```

> ```
> >>> r
> array([3.5, 1.14285714, 0.0, nan, 0.15625])
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido