# ¿Por qué no puedo redimensionar un array multidimensional a uno más pequeño con NumPy? En Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Estaba aprendiendo esta librería "NumPy" para Python, cree un array de 9x9 lleno de 9s con un `np.full((9,9),9)`:

```
[[9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]]
```

Y esta ahí todo bien, luego quise reducirla. Intente con un `a.reshape((3,3))`, y esperaba que me saliera algo así:

```
[[9 9 9]
 [9 9 9]
 [9 9 9]]
```

Lastimosamente, no puedo hacer eso, ya que me salta el sigueinte error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\papas.py", line 4, in <module>
    b = a.reshape((3,3))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 81 into shape (3,3)
```

Entoces, mi pregunta es: **¿Por qué no me deja redimensionar el array, o si hay otra manera de hacerlo, entonces cuál sería la manera correcta?** Entiendo que si fuera a redimensionar un 8x4 a un 6x13, no podía por son diferentes las relaciones 'fila-columna'. Pero en este caso son relativas (la forma original y la manera en que la quiero modificar). Esto lo digo porque 9 es divisible por 3. Adjunta el código completo, es muy corto:

**El código:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.full((9,9),9)
b = a.reshape((3,3))

print("Original: ")
print(a)

print("Reducida: ")
print(b)
```

Estoy seguro que esto es una novatada, muchas gracias de antemano. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.ndarray.reshape` espera que le pases unas dimensiones en las que pueda acomodar todos los items del anterior array. No quieres redimensionar, quieres hacer un rebanado del array que no es lo mismo.

Es decir, el número de elementos del array redimensionado y del original debe ser el mismo, solo se modifican sus dimensiones y se acomodan:

```
>>> a.reshape((27, 3))
array([[9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9]])

>>> a.reshape((81, 1))
array([[9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9],
       [9]])

>>> a.reshape((9, 3, 3))
array([[[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]],

       [[9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
```

Para hacer el rebanado simplemente:

> ```
> >>> a[:3, :3]
> array([[9, 9, 9],
>        [9, 9, 9],
>        [9, 9, 9]])
> ```

- [Obtener porción de una matriz (submatriz)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336768/obtener-porci%c3%b3n-de-una-matriz-submatriz/336804#336804)
- [¿Qué significa [::-1]?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/341559/15089)

eso se queda con los tres primeras columnas de las tres primeras filas. Ten en cuenta que ésto no crea una copia del array, es solo una vista:

```
>>> b = a[:3, :3]
>>> b[0, 0] = 15
>>> a
array([[15,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9]])
```

Si no quieres ésto puedes hacer una copia explícita:

```
b = a[:3, :3].copy()
```